# Flutter, Expanded Stack`s child cut/removed by other widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
          Container(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20, top: 16, bottom: 16),
            height: 68,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Positioned(
                          // top: 16,
                          left: 0,
                          // height: 40,
                          // width: 40,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 36,
                            width: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 4,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 120,
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

The black circle is wrapped by Expanded

But the space is invaded by others

how to prevent this??

I'd rather this give overflow to the right without clipping my stack widget.

[image]

Comment: it was because of padding. But is there a better way instead of clearing the padding? Stack is very difficult to dynamically set width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Positioned` in a `container` instead of `circle`.

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20, top: 16, bottom: 16),
          height: 68,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 36,
                width: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 50,
                top: 3,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-100,
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: hm.. I think it is not dynamic width.. (like using Expanded)

Comment: Which width you change dynamically circle or rectangle

Comment: I don't mind which one is, I am just doing experiment but like my question "Row( children: [ Expanded( child: Container(
child: Stack(children: <Widget>["    I want to start with this code

Comment: updated my answer check it for dynamic width  where I used mediaQuery width and need not use expanded under row.

Comment: my friend I do not think that is dynamic width.. What if you have mixture of irregularly sized widgets inside Stack children?

Comment: do you explain what you actually need?